# How to fetch upstream and resolve conflicts for a forked branch locally?

Tags: git, github, fork, branch, upstream

I have forked a Github Repo and raised PR for some contribution. Before getting merged, some other commits were made to the parent repo. To fetch upstream I need to resolve conflicts with the upstream. How do I fetch upstream locally and resolve those changes?

Comment: Have you created a branch for your feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork) for that, but a quick way to do it would be:

Assuming you created a fork and cloned your fork only:

First thing you need to do is to add a new remote that points to the upstream project.

In your local fork, run `git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git`

Fetch the remote: `git fetch upstream`

Be sure that you are in your branch you want to merge and run `git rebase upstream/<branch you want to merge to>`

This will move your branch to  and will add the commits from your branch on top of that.

If you encounter any merge conflicts in the process, you need to:

- resolve the conflict(s)
- `git add` the affected file(s)
- `git rebase --continue` to continue with rebasing

Once you are done, use `git push --force origin <your branch>` (you need to use the `--force` as you changed the branch history if you previously pushed your branch)